# List products by parent id's

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table: products
 ____________________________
|id | cat_id | title         |
|----------------------------|
| 1 |  14    | new bmw X5    |
| 2 |  9     | barbie horse  |
| 3 |  8     | cool iphone 11|
| 4 |  10    | new galaxy S6 |
|----------------------------|
```

```
table: categories
 _______________________________
|id   | cat_name    | parent_id |
|-------------------------------|
| 1   | smartphones | NULL      |
| 2   | cars        | NULL      |
| 3   | toys        | NULL      |
| 4   | Apple       | 1         |
| 5   | Nokia       | 1         |
| 6   | Samsung     | 1         |
| 7   | iphone 10   | 4         |
| 8   | iphone 11   | 4         |
| 9   | galaxy s5   | 6         |
| 10  | galaxy s6   | 6         |
| 11  | Audi        | 2         |
| 12  | BMW         | 2         |
| 13  | X3          | 12        |
| 14  | X5          | 12        |
| 15  | A6          | 11        |
| 16  | barbie      | 3         |
| 17  | transformer | 3         |
| 18  | horse       | 16        |
|-------------------------------|
```

i found a way to list the maincategories of every product

```
select  distinct id as subcat_id, cat_name as subcat_name, parent_id
from       (
            select      d6.parent_id as id6,
                        d5.parent_id as id5,
                        d4.parent_id as id4,
                        d3.parent_id as id3,
                        d2.parent_id as id2,
                        d1.parent_id as id1,
                        d1.id        as id0,
            from        categories d1
            left join   categories d2 on d2.id = d1.parent_id 
            left join   categories d3 on d3.id = d2.parent_id 
            left join   categories d4 on d4.id = d3.parent_id  
            left join   categories d5 on d5.id = d4.parent_id  
            left join   categories d6 on d6.id = d5.parent_id
            left join   products pro d1.id = pro.cat_id
           ) as h
inner join categories d on d.id in (id0, id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6)
where d.parent_id IS NULL order by 1
```

**but i want to have:**

show all products from category smartphones (id 1)
or

show me all products from category smartphones (id 1) AND Apple (id 4)

but how? recursiv search to all categories

Comment: MySQL 8.x or 5.x? It's easy in 8.x

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Recursive CTE (Common Table Expression) in MySQL 8.x. For example:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select
    p.id, p.cat_id, p.title,
    c.id as cid, c.parent_id as pid
  from products p
  join categories c on c.id = p.cat_id
  union all
  select
    n.id, n.cat_id, n.title,
    c.id as cid, c.parent_id as pid
  from n
  join categories c on c.id = n.pid  
)
select
  n.id, n.title, c.*
from n
join categories c on c.id = n.cid
where n.pid is null
```